# Asm volatile ("int $0x3") call restarts the machine

Tags: kernel, interrupt-handling

I am studying kernel development. To test my interrupt handler I need to run asm volatile ("idt $0x3") command. Whenever this command is called in my main.c, machine always restarts. I even tried to remove the interrupt handler. Nothing changed. What should I do?

gdt assembly:

```
[extern _start]

lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
jmp CODE_SEG:initgdt

initgdt:
mov ax, DATA_SEG     
mov ds, ax       
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax
mov ebp, 0x90000
mov esp, ebp
call _start ;main.c function
jmp $

gdt_star:

gdt_null:
dd 0x0      
dd 0x0      

gdt_code:
dw 0xffff   
dw 0x0010
db 0x00     
db 10011011b
db 01001111b
db 0x00 

gdt_data:
dw 0xffff
dw 0x0020
db 0x00
db 10010010b
db 01001111b
db 0x0              


gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
dw gdt_end - gdt_star - 1
dd gdt_star

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_star
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_star
```

descriptor_tables.c:

```
extern void idt_flush(uint32_t);
extern void isr0();
extern void isr1();
....
extern void isr31();


static void init_idt()
{
    idt_ptr.limit = sizeof(idt_entry_t) * 256 -1;
    idt_ptr.base  = (uint32_t)&idt_entries;

    memset((uint8_t*)&idt_entries, 0, sizeof(idt_entry_t)*256);

    idt_set_gate(0, (uint32_t)isr0, 0x08, 0x8E);
    idt_set_gate(1, (uint32_t)isr1, 0x08, 0x8E);
    ....
    idt_set_gate(31, (uint32_t)isr31, 0x08, 0x8E);

    idt_flush((uint32_t)&idt_ptr);
}

static void idt_set_gate(uint8_t num, uint32_t base, uint16_t sel, uint8_t flags)
{
   idt_entries[num].base_lo = base & 0xFFFF;
   idt_entries[num].base_hi = (base >> 16) & 0xFFFF;

   idt_entries[num].sel     = sel;
   idt_entries[num].always0 = 0;
   idt_entries[num].flags   = flags
}
```

interrupt.asm:

```
%macro ISR_NOERRCODE 1 
  [GLOBAL _isr%1]       
  _isr%1:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte %1
    jmp isr_common_stub
%endmacro

%macro ISR_ERRCODE 1
  [GLOBAL _isr%1]
  _isr%1:
    cli
    push byte %1
    jmp isr_common_stub
%endmacro

ISR_NOERRCODE 0
ISR_NOERRCODE 1
....
ISR_NOERRCODE 31

[EXTERN _isr_handler]

isr_common_stub:
pusha                    

mov ax, ds               
push eax                

mov ax, 0x10 
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

call _isr_handler

pop eax        
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

popa                    
add esp, 8     
sti
iret
```

isr.c:

```
void isr_handler(registers_t regs)
{
   uint8_t str[12] = "\ninterrupt:";
   str[11] = 0;
   puts(str, FALSE);
   itoa(str, 10, regs.int_no);
   puts(str, FALSE);
   str[0] = '\n';
   str[1] = 0;
   puts(str, TRUE);
}
```

kernel_entry.asm:

```
....
[global _idt_flush]
_idt_flush:
   mov eax, [esp+4]  
   lidt [eax]       
   ret
```

Comment: Did you set up your GDT and IDT? Without those interrupts won't do anything. Also if you can please link to the relevant code. My suspicion is that you haven't setup your GDT and IDT tables correctly

Comment: Without the relevant code it's kind of hard to guess the problem. Can you post some snippets of your IDT/GDT setup as well as your interrupt  handling code.

Comment: I see your ISR set up but no relevant code for IRQ setup. Not sure if that would cause it. Also have you tried having your isr_handler do nothing? I just want to make sure your puts and itoa functions aren't causing a processor exception.

Comment: No, none of those is the problem. Would you read my answer? I solved the problem but I still have questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the descriptor_tables.c C code to Assembly code and used following macro:

```
%macro IDT_ENTRY 1
dw _isr%1
dw 0x08
db 0x0
db 0x8E
dw 0x0000
%endmacro
```

Now, it works. But I am not sure why it did not accept the C code. Moreover, following macro did not work either:

```
%macro IDT_ENTRY 1
dw (_isr%1 - $$) & 0xFFFF
dw 0x08
db 0x0
db 0x8E
dw ((_isr%1 - $$) >> 16) & 0xFFFF
%endmacro
```

Again, I am not sure why the second macro is not working.